# Three.js import Collada animation not working

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, collada

I've been trying to export a Collada animated model to three js.

Here is the model:

http://bayesianconspiracy.com/files/model.dae

It is imported properly(I can see the model) but I can't get it to animate. I've been using the two Collada examples  that come with Three js. I've tried just replacing the path with the path to my model but it doesn't work. I've also tried tweaking some stuff but to no avail.

When the model is loaded I've checked the 'object.animations' object which seems to be loaded fine(can't tell for sure but there is lots of stuff in it).

I've also tried the Three.js editor:

http://threejs.org/editor/

which loads the model properly again but I can't play the animation : (

I am using Three JS r62 and Blender 2.68. Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that there are some errors in your file that disable animation.
I have opened your model.dae file with blender andI have noticed at least 2 errors OMHO.
They are in the following video : http://youtu.be/BGnVVpMNY4E .
You therefore might work a bit more on your model and if you need a step by step tutorial to animate your collada model into a THREE.JS based webgl viewport, then you can check this tutorial : http://jiteshmulchandani.com/?p=122

As mentioned on this page:

> Get the latest plugin from http://opencollada.org/ and export the model using the following options checked :
>   Normals
>   Triangulate
>   Enable export
>   Sample animation
>   **Note : When exported using the Autodesk Collada format, it doesn’t play skeletal animations.**

The corresponding demo is right here : http://jiteshmulchandani.com/zombie-outbreak/ColladaModelTest.html (to control the model, use ASDW keys)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look when I can. About the collada plugin - I can see only plugins for Maya and 3ds Max. Do you then mean that it's better to export the model from Maya?

Comment: I think there's something wrong in your exporting process. Have you tried to load a simpler animated collada file exported with your Blender configuration? Regarding Maya/3ds plugins,I have explored some collada models provided in the example codes, and they are exported from 3ds. But I am not saying that Blender can't, it's certainly a bit harder than export as -> collada file.

Comment: Another way of loading animation in three.js from Blender is the use of a JSON file as described here : http://graphic-sim.com/B_basic_export.html

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I loaded the js file using the three.js editor and when I tried to play the animation it just moved the model up(along the z axis) a bit. Now I am trying to export the model using Maya. It looks well good but when I try to import three js complains about this: "ColladaLoader: Could not find the skeleton for the skin."

Comment: Could you share the new version of your maya exported collada file? And have you checked this out : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2963 ?